# Admin consent does not work for scope User.Read.All in v2 App

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I downloaded the Azure sample to 'Build a multi-tenant daemon with the v2.0 endpoint' from here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2

I registered the application in `apps.dev.microsoft.com`, set the Application Permission scope to User.Read.All, and replaced the Application ID and generated password secret in Startup.Auth.cs in the code.

The sample code runs fine, except that the admin consent grant does not seem to work.

The code in `AccountController.RequestPermissions()` successfully builds and sends an admin consent request. The consent page displays the correct scope: "Read all users' full profiles". After providing consent, I am redirected to https://localhost:44316/Account/GrantPermissions?admin_consent=True&tenant=my-tenant-id, showing that the grant was successful. I also see the app show up in my Enterprise Applications on the Azure portal after that.

However the call to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users in `UsersController.Index` still results in a '403 Forbidden'. The error detail in Fiddler shows:

`"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."`

The JWT Bearer token in that request holds my correct tenant-id and a single role: "User.Read.All".

My account is global administrator of this tenant, and it can query users on graph.microsoft.io.

[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38124011/614665) dating June 30 suggests it is not yet possible to use admin_consent with App Model v2. The sample I downloaded however dates from late September and shows exactly this scenario, so I was hoping it is meanwhile supported.

Is admin_consent already supported in the App Model v2? If so, could anyone help me find out what is going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the instructions for the sample, if you are not using the scripts, pay close attention to step 5 in [Register the client app (daemon-console)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph#register-the-client-app-daemon-console)

Where it says:

> 5. In the list of pages for the app, select **API permissions**
>
> - Click the **Add a permission** button and then,
> - Ensure that the **Microsoft APIs** tab is selected
> - In the *Commonly used Microsoft APIs* section, click on **Microsoft Graph**
> - In the **Application permissions** section, ensure that the right permissions are checked:
>   **User.Read.All**
> - Select the **Add permissions** button

If you select **Delegated permissions** rather than **Application permissions**, you will get the following error when you run the sample:

```
Authorization_RequestDenied
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Very easy to make this simple error if you are not paying attention.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the Azure portal as well as the documentation has meanwhile been updated, making it less likely to make the Application- vs. Delegated Permissions mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing everything right.  We have an active issue on this topic, if you would like to partake, please join in on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2/issues/1